# Use lodash groupBy function to categorize objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, lodash

i have an array of products that each product has a category object. I need to organize by category and include the category object. GroupBy function include only one parameter.

the array of products

```
const data = [   
  {id: 1, 'name': 'produto1', category: {id: 1, name: 'shirts', description: 'super roupa'}},
  {id: 2, 'name': 'produto2', category: {id: 1, name: 'shirts', description: 'super roupa'}},
  {id: 3, 'name': 'produto3', category: {id: 2, name: 'jackets', description: 'super jackets'}},
  {id: 4, 'name': 'produto4', category: {id: 2, name: 'jackets', description: 'super jackets'}},    
]
```

expected result:

```
[
  {
    category: {id: 1, name: 'clothes', description: 'super roupa'}, 
    products:[{id:1, name: 'produt1'}, {id: 2, name: 'produto1'} ]
  },
  {
    category: {id: 2, name: 'jackets', description: 'super jackets'}, 
    products:[{id:3, name: 'produt3'}, {id: 4, name: 'produto4'} ]
  },
]
```

Comment: Please include your own attempts in the question.

Comment: *"This question does not show any research effort":* ...quoting from the down-vote button tooltip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by the `category.id`, and then map the each group to an object by taking the `category` from the 1st item in the group, and omitting `category` from all products:

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"name":"produto1","category":{"id":1,"name":"shirts","description":"super roupa"}},{"id":2,"name":"produto2","category":{"id":1,"name":"shirts","description":"super roupa"}},{"id":3,"name":"produto3","category":{"id":2,"name":"jackets","description":"super jackets"}},{"id":4,"name":"produto4","category":{"id":2,"name":"jackets","description":"super jackets"}}]

const result = _(data)
  .groupBy('category.id')
  .map(group => ({
    category: _.head(group).category,
    products: _.map(group, o => _.omit(o, 'category'))
  }))
  .value()

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Or the `_.flow()` function equivalent with lodash/fp:

```js
const { flow, groupBy, map, head, omit } = _

const fn = flow(
  groupBy('category.id'),
  map(group => ({
    category: head(group).category,
    products: map(omit('category'), group)
  }))
)

const data = [{"id":1,"name":"produto1","category":{"id":1,"name":"shirts","description":"super roupa"}},{"id":2,"name":"produto2","category":{"id":1,"name":"shirts","description":"super roupa"}},{"id":3,"name":"produto3","category":{"id":2,"name":"jackets","description":"super jackets"}},{"id":4,"name":"produto4","category":{"id":2,"name":"jackets","description":"super jackets"}}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution without lodash:

You could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the data array. [Destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the parameter to get `category` and [`rest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) of the properties separately. Here `rest` will have `id` and `name` properties. Then create an accumulator object with each unique category's `id` as key. Set the value to be the final objects needed in the output. If the key already exists, update it's `products` array. Else, add a new key to the accumulator. Then finally use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to convert this accumulator object to an array of required values

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"name":"produto1","category":{"id":1,"name":"shirts","description":"super roupa"}},{"id":2,"name":"produto2","category":{"id":1,"name":"shirts","description":"super roupa"}},{"id":3,"name":"produto3","category":{"id":2,"name":"jackets","description":"super jackets"}},{"id":4,"name":"produto4","category":{"id":2,"name":"jackets","description":"super jackets"}}]

const merged = data.reduce((acc, { category, ...rest }) => {
  acc[category.id] = acc[category.id] || { category, products: [] };
  acc[category.id].products.push(rest);
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(merged))
```